# JavaScript populate two form fields with Today's Date

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have the code in [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xg4zjufL/2/). But two things don't happen. Unchecking the box only affects one field (`entry_date`) and when I submit the form the field `expiration_date` does not get written to the DB -- the `entry_date` does. I have jerry rigged the script. I know *nothing* about JS so any tips would be welcome.

```js
function onCheck(checkbox) {
  var entry_date = document.getElementById('entry_date');
  var expiration_date = document.getElementById('expiration_date');
  entry_date.disabled = checkbox.checked;
  expiration_date.disabled = checkbox.checked;
  if (checkbox.checked) {
    //entry_date.value = new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10);
    //expiration_date.value = new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10);
    entry_date.valueAsDate = new Date();
    expiration_date.valueAsDate = new Date();
  }
  else
    entry_date.value = '';


}
```

```html
Day Guest<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" name="dayguest" onclick="onCheck(this);">
<!--If checkbox is checked date box is disabled-->

<br>

<!--Gets today's date and puts it as max-->
<label for="entry_date">Arrival Date</label>
<input type="date" id="entry_date" name="entry_date">
<br>
<label for="entry_date">Departure Date</label>
<input type="date" id="expiration_date" name="expiration_date">
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3kejsoaz/ updated fiddle

Comment: What’s that AND doing, that’s not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Your form code isn't included, so I can't speak to the backend/database issue, but the reason unchecking the box only affects one field is because your `else` statement only changes one value, not both:

```
entry_date.value = '';
```

Adding a corresponding statement to reset the second field will address that problem:

```
expiration_date.value = '';
```

Not related to the problem at hand, but your second `<label>` is corresponding to `entry_date` rather than `expiration_date` (fixed in the below snippet).

```js
function onCheck(checkbox) {
  var entry_date = document.getElementById('entry_date');
  var expiration_date = document.getElementById('expiration_date');
  entry_date.disabled = checkbox.checked;
  expiration_date.disabled = checkbox.checked;
  if (checkbox.checked) {
    //entry_date.value = new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10);
    //expiration_date.value = new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10);
    entry_date.valueAsDate = new Date();
    expiration_date.valueAsDate = new Date();
  } else {
    entry_date.value = '';
    expiration_date.value = '';
  }
}
```

```html
Day Guest<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" name="dayguest" onclick="onCheck(this);">
<!--If checkbox is checked date box is disabled-->

<br>

<!--Gets today's date and puts it as max-->
<label for="entry_date">Arrival Date</label>
<input type="date" id="entry_date" name="entry_date">
<br>
<label for="expiration_date">Departure Date</label>
<input type="date" id="expiration_date" name="expiration_date">
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is simple: you forgot to assign to `expiration_date.value` in the `else` block.

The second problem is that disabled inputs are not submitted in forms. If you want to prevent the user from changing the value, set the `readonly` attribute.

```js
function onCheck(checkbox) {
  var entry_date = document.getElementById('entry_date');
  var expiration_date = document.getElementById('expiration_date');
  if (checkbox.checked) {
    entry_date.valueAsDate = new Date();
    expiration_date.valueAsDate = new Date();
    entry_date.setAttribute("readonly", true);
    expiration_date.setAttribute("readonly", true);
  } else {
    entry_date.value = '';
    expiration_date.value = '';
    entry_date.removeAttribute("readonly");
    expiration_date.removeAttribute("readonly");
  }
}
```

```html
Day Guest<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" name="dayguest" onclick="onCheck(this);">
<!--If checkbox is checked date box is disabled-->

<br>

<!--Gets today's date and puts it as max-->
<label for="entry_date">Arrival Date</label>
<input type="date" id="entry_date" name="entry_date">
<br>
<label for="expiration_date">Departure Date</label>
<input type="date" id="expiration_date" name="expiration_date">
```